# How do I get my macro to stop if i cancel save a copy

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

Greetings one and all - a christmas puzzle for anyone still looking at this site...This works but if i decide to cancel the process (ie not save a file and stop the process at this stage) it doesn't svae the file but the following marco (filltolastrow2) is still activated how can I stop this happening?

```
Public Sub SaveaCopyIncomeSheet()
    Dim file_name As Variant
    file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Overdue Report - Draft", filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xls),*.xls")
    If file_name <> False Then
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
        MsgBox "File Saved!"
    End If
    filltolastrow2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You possibly want

```
If file_name <> False Then
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
   MsgBox "File Saved!"
   filltolastrow2
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
Public Sub SaveaCopyIncomeSheet()
    Dim file_name As Variant
    file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Overdue Report - Draft", filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xls),*.xls")

    If file_name = False Then GoTo E_NoFileName

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
    MsgBox "File Saved!"
    filltolastrow2

Exit Sub
E_NoFileName:
    MsgBox "File Not Saved"
End Sub
```

Comment: That's more or less an example of how NOT to use "GoTo". I am pretty sure you heard of "If - Then  - Else" ;-)

Comment: Well you are right I would Code it like your Solution (hence the "Alternative:") but I like to show some variety. The Solution is not illegal, does not make the code harder to understand and is simple so I tink it's ok :)